# Protractor - What is the difference between seleniumAddress and directConnect

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-grid, selenium-server

I'm not clear about what's the difference between run my protractor tests using:

```
directConnect: true/false,
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
```

And also, why this is working? What I'm using for run my tests?

> I've not declare any of the above options in my config file, and I've all my tests running.

This is the output when I run my tests:

```
[16:26:42] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:26:42] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[16:26:46] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://193.167.1.94:57674/wd/hub
```

I/local means that I'm running locally? Is directConnect the default option?

I saw I/hosted in some stack overflow post. That means that they are using an external grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**seleniumAddress**

You can give selenium server or selenium grid url to `seleniumAddress`.

You can start selenium server or grid on same or diff machine where test

script reside

**1.1) local selenium server**

```
 . Selenium server run on same machine where test scripts reside

 . When running test, browser opened on the machine where selenium server running

 . Communicate Path:  ( in same machine where test script reside)

    test script -> selenium server -> webdriver binary -> browser
```

**1.2) remote selenium server**

```
. Selenium server run on remote machine where test scripts **NOT** reside

. When running test, browser opened on the remote machine where selenium server running  

. Communicate Path: ( cross two machines )

   test script -> test script machine 
               -> selenium server  (on remote machine)
               -> webdriver binary (on remote machine)
               -> browser          (on remote machine)
```

**1.3) selenium grid**

```
. Grid use Master/Slave 

. Multiple Slave machines register to One Master machine

. Each Slave can install couple kinds of browsers

. Slave tell Master it can provide the kinds of browser and 
  max browser instances running in parallel when register to Master

. Master will determine each test open browser on which Slave 
  by test required browser type and not exceed the max browser instances on slave

. Communicate Path: ( cross three machines )

    test script -> test script machine 
                -> master machine
                -> selenium server  (on choosen slave machine)
                -> webdriver binary (on choosen slave machine)
                -> browser          (on choosen slave machine)
```

**directConnect**

```
. When directConnect: true, seleniumAddress will be ignored (if both configured)

. Only chrome and firefox support directConnect so far

. Communicate Path: ( in same machine where test script reside) 

    test script -> webdriver binary -> browser
```

**Using seleniumAddress** you can see the logs of test script communicate to webdriver in the terminate window where you start the selenium server/grid.

From the logs you can get information like following:

- test script use which locator to find element
- the step to find/operate element complete or failed
- when test case failed, it failed on communicating which element.

These information is very useful to debug test script

**Using directConnect** by default protractor won't start webdriver binary in separate terminate window and won't direct the communicate log into file.

So it's not suite for debug test script.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. so without adding neither config, I'm using direct connect at this moment, right?

Comment: if you not config `directConnect` , it default as false. So protractor will expect `seleniumAddress` be configured, if you also not config it. Protractor running will fail.

Comment: But this is how I have my conf.ts right now and it's not running with fail.

Comment: framework: 'jasmine2',
baseUrl: 'mysite',
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

Those are the configs that I have. If you re-read my question, one of my concerns was about this.

Comment: @Juan if `seleniumAddress` is not specified protractor will assume the selenium server is not already running and start a new instance of the server when it launches. I touched on this in my answer. Neither `directConnect` nor `seleniumAddress` are mandatory values and it is common not to have either declared in your conf unless you specifically need them.

Comment: @Dublin Awesome, that makes sense. Sorry for asked again but since I will start configuring Selenoid or Zalenium for my framework, first I wanted to be clear about what I've done so far.

Answer (score 2):

`seleniumAddress` is the location where the selenium server is running. If this is not specified then a new selenium server instance will be created when your framework is executed (usually on the default selenium port 4444).

`directConnect` is different, it allows you to send command directly to the browser drivers, skipping the seleniumServer altogether. It's definition according to the conf linked below is:

> If true, Protractor will connect directly to the browser Drivers
>   at the locations specified by chromeDriver and firefoxPath. Only Chrome
>   and Firefox are supported for direct connect.

[This](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts) is a link to the sample conf.ts file with all options and explanations listed along the default settings. I find it a very useful reference.

Also see this [relevant prior thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618472/directconnecttrue-vs-starting-seleniumserver-at-some-port-in-protractor) for more information.

Comment: I checked those links, thanks. But my main doubt was about what is the default rule for the text execution, because I don't have directConnect nor seleniumAddress in my config file, and it's running, So my question is, did you know if directConnect is the default rule?

Comment: @JuanCañete DirectConnect is false by default. In the config linked it should state the default settings for the available properties. [Here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/37bef24331c1012bfc2cc7d3fa259a00e69bd192/lib/config.ts#L230) is a link to where the directConnect setting is listed. This link is very useful and worth bookmarking, I reference it regularly.